# Move NA to the bottom

Tags: r, data.table

I'm looking for a simple way to move all rows with at least one NA to the bottom of the dataframe/datatable. For example :

```
> df <- data.table(aaa=c(1,2,3,4,NA,6,7),
                   bbb=c(1,9,5,NA,3,NA,9),
                   ccc=c(NA,3,NA,4,8,NA,2)
                   )
> df
   aaa bbb ccc
1:   1   1  NA
2:   2   9   3
3:   3   5  NA
4:   4  NA   4
5:  NA   3   8
6:   6  NA  NA
7:   7   9   2
```

would become something like this :

```
> df2 <- moveNAtoBottom(df)
> df2
   aaa bbb ccc
1:   2   9   3
2:   7   9   2
3:   1   1  NA
4:   3   5  NA
5:   4  NA   4
6:  NA   3   8
7:   6  NA  NA
```

I.e. all columns with no NA at the top.

Notes :

- for now, I don't really care if any sorting is applied or not to the rows, or if the order is kept, or reversed... as long as the table now has two parts, the top one without NAs, the bottom one with NAs
- this can be on dataframes or datatables
- dependencies are ok

Better yet, if I could be able to specify the columns on which the search for the NAs must be applied. E.g., still with the previous example :

```
> df3 <- moveNAtoBottom(df, applyTo = c("bbb", "ccc"))
> df3
   aaa bbb ccc
1:   2   9   3
2:  NA   3   8
3:   7   9   2
4:   1   1  NA
5:   3   5  NA
6:   4  NA   4
7:   6  NA  NA
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple base R solution could be:

```
> df <- data.frame(aaa=c(1,2,3,4,NA,6,7),
+                  bbb=c(1,9,5,NA,3,NA,9),
+                  ccc=c(NA,3,NA,4,8,NA,2))
> ok <- complete.cases(df)
> rbind(df[ok,], df[!ok,])
  aaa bbb ccc
2   2   9   3
7   7   9   2
1   1   1  NA
3   3   5  NA
4   4  NA   4
5  NA   3   8
6   6  NA  NA
```

And to select only some columns :

```
> ok <- complete.cases(df[, c("bbb","ccc")])
> rbind(df[ok,], df[!ok,])
  aaa bbb ccc
2   2   9   3
5  NA   3   8
7   7   9   2
1   1   1  NA
3   3   5  NA
4   4  NA   4
6   6  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(rowSums(is.na(.)))
```

Which gives:

```
#  aaa bbb ccc
#1   2   9   3
#2   7   9   2
#3   1   1  NA
#4   3   5  NA
#5   4  NA   4
#6  NA   3   8
#7   6  NA  NA
```

Or should you want to specify the column names:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(rowSums(is.na(select_(., 'bbb:ccc'))))
```

Which gives:

```
#  aaa bbb ccc
#1   2   9   3
#2  NA   3   8
#3   7   9   2
#4   1   1  NA
#5   3   5  NA
#6   4  NA   4
#7   6  NA  NA
```

Comment: Works well, thanks. Can I ask a question about `dplyr` ? Why does it work with the pipe, but not without ? If they work in the same way as `magrittr`'s pipe, one would think that `arrange(rowSums(is.na(select_(df, 'bbb:ccc'))))` would work too, no ?

Comment: You need to specify on which `data` you want to perform the `arrange()`: try `arrange(df, rowSums(is.na(select_(df, 'bbb:ccc'))))`

Answer (score 5):

As the OP used `data.table`, one option with `data.table` is loop through the columns with `lapply`, check whether it is NA (`is.na`), get the row wise sum with `Reduce`, and use that to `order` the rows of 'df'.

```
df[order(Reduce(`+`, lapply(df, is.na)))]
#    aaa bbb ccc
#1:   2   9   3
#2:   7   9   2
#3:   1   1  NA
#4:   3   5  NA
#5:   4  NA   4
#6:  NA   3   8
#7:   6  NA  NA
```

And here's a similar approach:

```
df[, anyna := FALSE]
for (k in names(df)) df[!(anyna), anyna := is.na(get(k))]
df[order(anyna)][, anyna := NULL][]
```

Comment: Nice. There is an unexported function `is_na` that will be quite useful here. Perhaps we should export it.

Comment: It is available in the stable version as well. Just not exported.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
na=apply(df,1,function(x)sum(is.na(x)))

df[order(na),]
```

Or a function

```
moveNAtoBottom<-function(df, applyTo=NULL){
  df<-as.data.frame(df)
  if (is.null(applyTo)) applyTo=colnames(df)
  na=rowSums(is.na(df[,applyTo,drop=F]))
  data.table(df[order(na),])
}

moveNAtoBottom(df)
moveNAtoBottom(df,c("ccc", "aaa"))

   aaa bbb ccc
1:   2   9   3
2:   4  NA   4
3:   7   9   2
4:   1   1  NA
5:   3   5  NA
6:  NA   3   8
7:   6  NA  NA
```